# How to add a splash screen theme to ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: boot, display, 22.04, themes, plymouth

I am using **Ubuntu 22.04** on my **dell laptop [ Intel i3, 64-bit]**. During the booting process, the screen only show a black screen. I wants to show a **`custom image or gif`** during the booting process, but don't know how? If anyone knows, please help...

Comment: since you have "plymouth" and "themes" added as tags, I assume you know that the solution is to install a plymouth theme (or create your own)? Did you try this yet, and what were the results?

Comment: Hello #Esther, I just installed a plymouth theme from gnome-look. The recent one I tried to install gives error about plymouth, but after trying another one, it is working now. I think the problem was with that particular theme.  Thanks for your help, the problem has solved now..

Answer (score 1):

after searching some, I found an answer. There are plymouth splash screen themes are on [gnme-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/find?search=plymouth). I used this [Vortex Ubuntu theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1462682) available. The installation steps are:

1. Open a terminal inside the "vortex-ubuntu" folder (right-click on
   the folder end select "open in terminal)
2. make the "install" file executable by running the following command:

   sudo chmod +x install
3. run the "install" file with the following command:

   sudo ./install

That's all. Now reboot.

My plymouth: [image]